# What is the Javascript equivelant for the Visual Basic function "GetRef"?

Tags: javascript

Here's an example of the code i'm working with converting

```
set clientCode = getRef("ToggleCoDebtorUseDebtorLastName")
```

I've done quite a bit of googling and i have been unable to find an answer

Thanks

Comment: `var clientCode = ToggleCoDebtorUseDebtorLastName;` Just this !

Comment: Or `var clientCode = window["ToggleCoDebtorUseDebtorLastName"];`

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**=** is the Javascript equivalent of **GetRef** of VBScript!

> In VBScript, an action function that needs to be invoked in response to an event is called by using ***'GetRef(functionName)'***
>
> In Javascript, the function can be called directly by using the '=' operator.

**1. Calling a function for 'on-load' event In VBScript**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Function MyFunction()
   Dim Greeting
   Greeting = "Hello World!"
   MsgBox Greeting
End Function

Set Window.Onload = GetRef("MyFunction")
</SCRIPT>
```

**2. Calling a function for 'on-load' event In JavaScript**

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }
  window.onload = myFunction;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very informative! I learned something new today!